# How to include another if function within a combined if, vlookup and index function?

Tags: excel

My data looks like:

```
Colums C,D,E,F

Row 1 4,10,40,F

Row 2 4,12,48,F

Row 3 4,14,56,F

Row 4 3,16,48,F

Row 5 1,18,18,F

Row 6 1,20,10,F

Row 7 0,22,0,0
```

My foucs is on column F. My current array formula in column F is:

```
=IF(C31=0,VLOOKUP(INDEX($C$30:$C$38,MIN(($C$30:C30*D31)-$E$30:E30)),$C$30:$E$38,1),"F")
```

In case column C is is equal to 0, I want the formula of column F to return the value of column C,which has the respective minimum difference between column C (allrowsbefore) * column D (currentrow) and E(respective, all rows before). For instance, in row 2 that minimization problem would equal:C1*D2-E1, if C2 would be equal to 0.

However, now i want column F formular to only choose a value of C which is unequal to 0.

Hence, in column **F7** i want column F to give me the value 1, as this is a C value which is bigger as 0 and has the respective min difference between (C6*D7)-E6. 
(For value 4 of C it would be 32 and for value 3 of C it would be 18).

**How and where do i include the if condition, that the value of C chosen has to be bigger as 1, into my existing formula ?**

Thanks a lot for helping out, its much appreciated!!! In case i need to split up my existing formula that would be alright, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reread your question more carefully after making my earlier comment, and I think I understand better now. To make sure you get the smallest value greater than 0, you use the following according to [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/60116):

```
=MIN(IF(A1:A10>0,A1:A10))
```

So your formula in F7 should look like this for the ranges you described:

```
=IF(C7=0,VLOOKUP(INDEX($C$1:$C$7,MIN((IF($C$1:$C$7>0,$C$1:$C$7)*D6)-$E$1:$E$7)),$C$1:$E$7,1),"F")
```

**EDIT**

Okay. I think I finally understand the question. :)

1. If Cx <> 0, Fx = Cx
2. If Cx = 0, Fx = the address of the cell in Column C that produces minimum of (C1 * D7 - E1, C2 * D7 - E2, ..., CN * D7 - EN)

From what I know of Excel, I don't think you can do this with a single formula. `INDEX` and `VLOOKUP` both look for values in the worksheet, but you're trying to work from the value of a calculation (`MIN`). Using the array formula to find that value is really smart. But once we get the value (4 in this case), we can't use that to look up the address of the cell in column C that produced that result. I really can't think of any way to do this without a macro. Are you able to do that?

**EDIT: Macro Solution**

This is a little quick and dirty, but it passed the test. Make sure to save your workbook as a Macro-Enabled workbook. Hit Alt+F11 to open the macro editor. You might need to insert a new module. You can do this by right-clicking the workbook project in the project explorer on the left.

[image: Add module]

Once you've done this, double-click on the module. You should get a blank white text editor on the right. Paste the following code into that window:

```
Public Function MinimumC()

    Dim rngCurrent As Range
    Set rngCurrent = Application.ThisCell

    Dim rngMin As Range
    Dim minimum As Long
    minimum = 100000000

    Dim tmp As Long

    Dim rngC As Range
    Set rngC = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C" & rngCurrent.Row - 1)

    For Each c In rngC.Cells
        If c.Value2 <> 0 Then
            tmp = c.Value2 * rngCurrent.Offset(0, -2).Value2 - c.Offset(0, 2)
            If tmp < minimum Then
                    minimum = tmp
                    Set rngMin = c
                End If
            End If
        Next c

    MinimumC = rngMin.Value2

End Function
```

Save the workbook. You can now close the code editor.

Now you can use the following formula in F1 and copy down column F: `=IF(C1<>0,C1,MinimumC())`.

This will work as long as the value of `C1 * Dy - E1` is never greater than 100000000. :)

Comment: Thanks, @tmoore82, thats exactly what I intendet to do! Nevertheless, applied in a moving reference context ( as i do not know in which row column C has a 0 value ), the above formula does not work.I used the following formula: IF(C7=0,VLOOKUP(INDEX($C$1:C7,MIN((IF($C$1:C7>0,$C$1:C7)*D6)-$E$1:E7)),$C$1:E7,1),"F")<br/> Any idea why it still produces the 0 in cell C7, instead of the value 1?

Comment: What formula are you using in column C?

Comment: The table above is only a simplification of my problem. In the real data set, column C formula is the following:        =IF(INDEX('Available packages '!$B$9:$B$158;Match('Overall simulation'!N13;'Available packages '!$C$9:$C$158;0));""). It can be any integer between 0 and 150.

Comment: Would it be too much of an oversimplification that if C7 is not 0, F7 = C7. If C7 = 0, then F7 = the minimum value from column C?

Comment: In other words, formula for F7 would be `=IF(C7<>0,C7,MIN(IF($C$1:$C$7>0,$C$1:$C$7)))`

Comment: The first part of what you say is correct: if C7 is not 0, F7 = C7. However, the formula in C should produce the minimum value from column C for which the respective column C* (times) the current round column D - (minus) the respective column E is minimized.

Comment: In other words, the formula is column C7 should calculated that 4(respective column C)*22(current cound D) - 56 (respective round E) = 32 ; 3(respective column C)*22(current cound D) - 48 (respective round E) = 18; 1(respective column C)*22(current cound D) - 20 (respective round E) = 2 and 0 (respective column C)*22(current cound D) - 0 (respective round E) = 0 and then choose the value 1, as this minimized the difference between the respective column C* (times) the current round column D - (minus) the respective column E and is unequal to 0.

Comment: I have tried this formula too:                                                     =WENN(C31=0;INDEX($C$31:C31;WENN(MIN(WENN($C$31:C31>0;$C$31:C31*D31:D31-$E$31:E31));$B$31:B31));"F")                                                                But this produces the value 4 in column C7 (C1-C6= F). This formula seems more resonable to me, though it again does not seem to fulfil what i want. Id be glad if u could have another look at it.

Comment: The above formular in english is the following:                =IF(C31=0;INDEX($C$31:C31;IF(MIN(IF($C$31:C31>0;$C$31:C31*D31:D31-$E$31:E3‌​1));$B$31:B31));"F")

Comment: the edited version of your answer is **exactly** what I want to do. However, I never used macros, but I am eager to learn, so if you could hint me in the right direction, I would be greatful. The only other idea I had to solve that problem was to use a IF-INDEX-Match-if formula and to incorporate the number of rows as the look up value but also this didnt work.

Comment: For the macro, there are a couple of different ways to implement it. Do you need it to run every time you enter a new row of data, or can it just be run once for column F after all the other values are entered?

Comment: 1.I need to run it every time i enter a new row of data                                                                  2. It should always only include the previous rows and the current one (never any row below the cell)                                                                3. Plus your definition, in step 2, the adress of the column C that produces the above mentioned minimum should also be >0.

Comment: Ok. I have an idea of how I would do this. I will need some time to work on it and test. In the meantime, if you want to try it yourself, there are good tutorials on writing macros here: http://www.homeandlearn.org/add-the-developer-toolbar-to-excel.html

Comment: tmoore82 Thanks for putting that much time and effort in it. I really appriciate it, have been stuck with that for 2 weeks now. Next thing tomorrow morning I will get started. Thanks again.

Comment: It works on the example data, perfect. My real data looks similar to the example data. Could you tell me how i need to change the existing macro code into the following 2 formulas for colmun BG and BN respectively?: (1:for column BG) Step 1: If(And(AZ>0;BA>0;BB>0);Concatenate(AZ;BA;BB)), Step 2(macro): otherwise, the adress cell of Concatenate (AZ;BA;BB) to minimize the following difference (AZn*BCx+BAn*BDx+BBn*BEx)-BFn

Comment: (2 - for column BN) If I have two times the above: Step 1:If(And(AZ>0;BA>0;BB>0;BH>0;BI>0;BJ>0);0, Step 2: otherwise the adress of the cell either concatenate (AZ;BA;BB) or concatenate (BH;BI;BJ) to minimize (AZn*BCx+BAn*BDx+BBn*BEx)-BFn or (BHn*BKx+BIn*BLx+BJn*BMx)-BNn .In this case i need to find the adress of either concatenate (AZ;BA;BB) or concatenate (BH;BI;BJ) with the min difference. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This discussion is starting to take up a lot of real estate. Since this solved your original problem, could you mark my response as the answer and post your follow-up as a new question? I think that will make it easier to continue the conversation.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out this much. I am really grateful! In case you still have time and wanna help me finish my last part of my coding, check out the new question: How to implement an advanced look up macro in excel? Again, thanks for taking the time. cheers

Comment: I will help when I can. A lot going on the next couple days, but I do want to see it through. :)